# makefile missing separator on cygwin

Tags: makefile, cygwin, separator

I can't figure out why I'm getting the error

```
library.mak:95: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

When I use make on cygwin. The code at that specific spot is

```
$(eval $(RULES))

$(EXAMPLES) $(TESTPROGS) $(TOOLS): $(THIS_LIB) $(DEP_LIBS)
$(TESTPROGS): $(SUBDIR)$(LIBNAME)

examples: $(EXAMPLES)
```

Comment: What is `$(RULES)` equal to ?

Comment: I can't properly indent this comment, but here you go.
`define RULES
$(EXAMPLES) $(TESTPROGS) $(TOOLS): %$(EXESUF): %.o
        $$(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $$@ $$^ -l$(FULLNAME) $(FFEXTRALIBS)      $$(ELIBS)`

Comment: You might want to move the above info in the comments to your question (hit the `|edit|` link above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try to:

git config --global core.autocrlf false

And checkout again the repository?

I'm wondering if the \r\n isn't at fault here...