# Problems compiling ffmpeg on windows using cygwin

Tags: windows, bash, ffmpeg, cygwin

I've been having a lot of trouble recently compiling ffmpeg on windows. I'm currently using the cgywin terminal to run the code. I've tried following many of the most popular tutorials on the web but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm currently using this tutorial as a guide http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/

**Where I'm at:**

I've created a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

NDK=C:/Users/jrblain/Development/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514/android-ndk-r9
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64
function build_one
{
./configure --target-os=linux \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --extra-libs="-lgcc" \
    --arch=arm \
    --cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
    --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
    --sysroot=$PLATFORM \
    --extra-cflags=" -O3 -fpic -DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -Dipv6mr_interface=ipv6mr_ifindex -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS " \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --extra-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog" \
    --disable-everything \
    --enable-demuxer=mov \
    --enable-demuxer=h264 \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --enable-protocol=file \
    --enable-avformat \
    --enable-avcodec \
    --enable-decoder=rawvideo \
    --enable-decoder=mjpeg \
    --enable-decoder=h263 \
    --enable-decoder=mpeg4 \
    --enable-decoder=h264 \
    --enable-parser=h264 \
    --disable-network \
    --enable-zlib \
    --disable-avfilter \
    --disable-avdevice \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG

make clean
make  -j4 install
$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar d libavcodec/libavcodec.a inverse.o
$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld -rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib  -soname libffmpeg.so -shared -nostdlib  -z,noexecstack -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $PREFIX/libffmpeg.so libavcodec/libavcodec.a libavformat/libavformat.a libavutil/libavutil.a libswscale/libswscale.a -lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog  --warn-once  --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/libgcc.a
}

#arm v6
#CPU=armv6
#OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-marm -march=$CPU"
#PREFIX=./android/$CPU 
#ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
#build_one

#arm v7vfpv3
CPU=armv7-a
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -marm -march=$CPU "
PREFIX=./android/$CPU
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
build_one

#arm v7vfp
#CPU=armv7-a
#OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -marm -march=$CPU "
#PREFIX=./android/$CPU-vfp
#ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
#build_one

#arm v7n
#CPU=armv7-a
#OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -marm -march=$CPU -mtune=cortex-a8"
#PREFIX=./android/$CPU 
#ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=--enable-neon
#build_one

#arm v6+vfp
#CPU=armv6
#OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-DCMP_HAVE_VFP -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -marm -march=$CPU"
#PREFIX=./android/${CPU}_vfp 
#ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
#build_one
```

I then followed steps 4-6 of this post [Does anyone find this useful? - Compiling FFMPEG on Windows with Cywin and NDK r5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665039/does-anyone-find-this-useful-compiling-ffmpeg-on-windows-with-cywin-and-ndk-r) which consists of

```
4 - Open the file 'configure' in the root of the FFMPEG directory in a text editor.

5 - Comment out lines 2073, 2074 and 2075.

6 - Below 2075, add the following line:

TMPDIR=c:/cygwin/tmp
```

When I ran the script in cgywin I got this result:

```
    install prefix            ./android/armv7-a
source path               .
C compiler                C:/Users/jrblain/Development/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
ARCH                      arm (armv7-a)
big-endian                no
runtime cpu detection     yes
ARMv5TE enabled           yes
ARMv6 enabled             yes
ARMv6T2 enabled           yes
VFP enabled               yes
NEON enabled              yes
THUMB enabled             no
debug symbols             yes
strip symbols             yes
optimize for size         no
optimizations             yes
static                    yes
shared                    no
postprocessing support    no
new filter support        no
network support           no
threading support         pthreads
safe bitstream reader     yes
SDL support               no
opencl enabled            no
texi2html enabled         no
perl enabled              no
pod2man enabled           no
makeinfo enabled          no

External libraries:
zlib

Enabled decoders:
h263                    mjpeg                   rawvideo
h264                    mpeg4

Enabled encoders:

Enabled hwaccels:

Enabled parsers:
h263                    h264                    mpeg4video

Enabled demuxers:
h264                    mov

Enabled muxers:

Enabled protocols:
file

Enabled filters:

Enabled bsfs:

Enabled indevs:

Enabled outdevs:

License: LGPL version 2.1 or later
Creating config.mak, config.h, and doc/config.texi...
libavutil/avconfig.h is unchanged

WARNING: C:/Users/jrblain/Development/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-pkg-config not found, library detection may fail.
library.mak:105: *** missing separator.  Stop.
library.mak:105: *** missing separator.  Stop.
C:\Users\jrblain\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514\android-ndk-r9\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: ,noexecstack: unknown -z option
C:\Users\jrblain\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514\android-ndk-r9\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: use the --help option for usage information
```

After this script runs I get some new files within my ffmpeg folder. They are .config, config(header), config.mak , config.fate. The android folder is never created like it is supposed to. I'm also not sure where the library.mak error is coming from considering that it came with ffmpeg download.

I'm not sure where this i'm going wrong in all of this. I feel like the fact that I'm using windows will make this build process different.

Comment: Check line 105 of `library.mak`.  It's probably missing a `TAB` character at the beginning of the line.

Comment: I added the tab but it resulted in the error of 'library.mak:105: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.' any ideas?

Comment: Here's an answer to a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634318/makefile-missing-separator-on-cygwin

Comment: Shouldn't every instance of `c:/` be `/cygdrive/c/` instead?

Answer (score 2):

The first error say "WARNING: C:/.../arm-linux-androideabi-pkg-config not found, library detection may fail." So I suggest to fix the path.

'C:/' is not a POSIX path. Cygwin programs are able to translate it (with a warning).

```
cd 'c:' # works. cd is a built-in command
ls 'c:' # doesn't work
ls 'c:/' # works (edited)
```

The documentation about how the Cygwin maps [POSIX- and Win32-style paths](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames).

From my experience you have issue when you mix slashs and back-slashs or when you call Windows native command from Cygwin. [Example](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-effectively.html):

```
javac -cp "$(cygpath -pw "$CLASSPATH")" hello.java
```

In my opinion, you should hardcode a POSIX path, or use the following command:

```
cygpath -u 'c:' # the relevant command provided by Cygwin
(cd 'c:' && pwd) # a tip, useful if you want a portable syntax
```

But maybe I am complety wrong. I suppose you already check the path

```
ls 'C:/Users/jrblain/Development/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-pkg-config'
```

And I supppose you already check the line 105 of your mk file (tabulation and linux **line feed**).

Comment: @BenVoigt, you're right. I tested with 'c:' that is different of 'c:/'. ls was probably a bad example.
So I fix my answer to say mainly "use POSIX path is better". And I opint other possible root causes...