# Issue in importing opencv with Cygwin

Tags: opencv, cygwin

I am using Cygwin for one of my project. I have installed opencv during cygwin installation itself.

[image]

From the above picture, it is clear that opencv 2.4 version is already installed in cygwin.

But when I try import cv2 in the console, I am getting the error "No module named cv".

[image]

Since the import of cv2 was not successful, I installed the wheel file of opencv manually in the cygdrive terminal. But I am not able to access opencv in cygwin yet.

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: please provide details of your operation. You need to make us able to replicate your commands to identify the problem. We can not guess your typing ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I guess it is now clear. Any help is appreciable

Answer (score 1):

Issue was with the environmental variable set for Cygwin.

One easy way to do is : instead of installing cygwin's python, it is easy to use the machine's default python installed. All it needs is just to set the environmental variable of the python path.

Comment: I have used this method. Basically, if I'm not using `cv2`, I simply enter `python3 my_python_program.py` into the Cygwin terminal.. When I need to use `cv2`, I enter the following into the Cygwin terminal: `/cygdrive/c/Users/13852/AppData/Local\Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe my_python_and_cv2_program.py`.  
However, if you're using a anything that's feeding in files from Cygwin, you can run into trouble. Since filenames and filepaths are often used in `cv2` (at least by me), you'll need to use `cygpath -w`. I think this is going to require an answer, but I want to OP to know this info.

Answer (score 1):

I want you to know, @Kathiravan_Natarajan , that your solution is great, and I've used it before to great success. I'm going to put in a little bit more detail about what steps must be followed, as you said, in order

> to use the machine's default python installed

I am not, however, going to change the Cygwin environment variables. I want to use Cygwin's `python3` whenever I can. When I need to use `cv2`, I'll simply give the full path to my Windows installation of `python`. **Warning: If you use Windows' `python` in Cygwin and try to feed it files/paths/etc. from Cygwin, you can run into problems. I'll discuss these in the *Path Issues* section**

Okay, just in Cygwin (and from its terminal), I have

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE ~
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE ~
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
```

Now, from `CMD`, for my Windows stuff.

```
C:\Windows\system32>where python
C:\Users\bballdave025\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
C:\Users\bballdave025\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
C:\Users\bballdave025\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
C:\Users\bballdave025\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

C:\Windows\system32>:: Ignore that last one - it takes you to the Microsoft Store

C:\Windows\system32>python --version
Python 3.8.2
```

**A Working Example of the Method Described by @Kathiravan_Natarajan**

Okay. Let's get a quick script that doesn't need `cv2`. I'm leading in to the possible issues with types of paths as we do this. We'll use bash heredocs.

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE ~
$ cat > my_pwd.py<<EOF
> #!/usr/bin/python3
> # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
> #
> import os
>
> print(os.getcwd())
> EOF
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE ~
$ chmod +x my_pwd.py
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE ~
$ # If you wanted, you could use `./my_pwd.py`, but that doesn't go to my point
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE ~
$ python3 my_pwd.py
/home/bballdave025
```

Now, even though this isn't what we'll usually want to do, let's run the script with the Windows version. (Since we don't usually want to do this, I haven't put the Windows version of Python on Cygwin's path).

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE ~
$ /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python my_pwd.py
C:\cygwin64\home\bballdave025
```

If it's really bugging you to type in the long path for `python` see the first footnote<sup>1</sup>.

I suggest running `rm my_pwd.py` in Cygwin to get rid of an unnecessary file.

Hopefully, that gives you some idea why we don't want to use Windows' `python` over Cygwin's while in Cygwin - though Cygwin itself could *probably* handle this path, but we'll discuss this in the *Path Issues* section.

**CV2 and Paths**

Now that we've used code *without* `cv2`, let's look at code *with* `cv2`.

From Windows `CMD`, be sure you have `opencv` for Python, and.

```
python -m pip install opencv-python
```

Now, I'll illustrate with a couple of scripts, one `bash` and one `python`, that deals with one directory containing five images.

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ ls
image_1.png  image_2.png  image_3.png  image_4.png  image_5.png
```

Now, code for two scripts. The first one is the `python` script, which will stay the same. The second one is the problem-showing (i.e. broken) version of the shell script for Cygwin.

```py
#!/cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#@file : show_img_and_wait.py
#
import cv2
import sys

this_img_fname = sys.argv[1]
print("Let us show {}".format(this_img_fname))
this_img = cv2.imread(this_img_fname)
cv2.imshow(this_img_fname, this_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
print("[Trust me that {} showed up fine.]".format(this_img_fname))
print("Now, we are done showing it.")
```

This next code is for showing the problem, only. IT WON'T WORK<sup>2</sup> - it will give errors and won't display anything!

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#
#@file broken_img_displays_from_path.sh
#

find /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win \
      -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.png" | \
           sort > tmp_imagepaths.txt

while read -r line; do
  img_fname="${line}"
  "/cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/"\
"python" -u show_img_and_wait.py "${img_fname}"
done < tmp_imagepaths.txt

rm tmp_imagepaths.txt
```

From Cygwin's terminal:

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ chmod +x show_img_and_wait.py
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ chmod +x broken_img_displays_from_path.sh
```

Let's first test the `python` code. Note that because of the shebang line (the one starting with `#!`), we can run it and have Windows `python` take care of everything. The line I have showing that there's no display is to reinforce the fact that everything is run through Windows. Also remember that there will be no path issue because we're using an image in the working directory.

(Also note that, trying Cygwin's `python`, we get an error saying there's no `cv2`; running `python3 -m pip install opencv-python` fails, at least today, 2020-05-01, epoch ts: `$ date +'%s'` `=>` `1588360101`. That's the reason for the OP's question.)

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ echo $DISPLAY

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ ./show_img_and_wait.py image_1.png
Let us show image_1.png
[Trust me that image_1.png showed up fine.]
Now, we are done showing it.
```

Now, let's try the `bash` script from Cygwin.

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ ./broken_img_displays_from_path.sh
Let us show /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win/image_1.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "show_img_and_wait.py", line 11, in <module>
    cv2.imshow(this_img_fname, this_img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\wi
ndow.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in fu
nction 'cv::imshow'

Let us show /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win/image_2.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "show_img_and_wait.py", line 11, in <module>
    cv2.imshow(this_img_fname, this_img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\wi
ndow.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in fu
nction 'cv::imshow'

Let us show /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win/image_3.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "show_img_and_wait.py", line 11, in <module>
    cv2.imshow(this_img_fname, this_img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\wi
ndow.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in fu
nction 'cv::imshow'

Let us show /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win/image_4.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "show_img_and_wait.py", line 11, in <module>
    cv2.imshow(this_img_fname, this_img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\wi
ndow.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in fu
nction 'cv::imshow'

Let us show /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win/image_5.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "show_img_and_wait.py", line 11, in <module>
    cv2.imshow(this_img_fname, this_img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\wi
ndow.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in fu
nction 'cv::imshow'
```

Those errors are a bit cryptic. Let's discuss what's going on.

**Path Issues** (and solution)

What's happening here is that Windows `python` and its version of `cv2` expect a Windows-style path. However, as shown from the output, it's getting a Cygwin version, e.g.

`Let us show /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win/image_1.png`

Windows `python`/`cv2` would like to see, e.g.

`Let us show C:\Users\bballdave025\Desktop\testing_cv2_python_win\image_1.png`<sup>3</sup>.

This is one example of why we need to keep track of things like paths when using the slick solution of Windows `python` on the Cygwin terminal.

The solution is to use [`cygpath`](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html) with the `-w` flag. Here's a modified `bash` script that will allow the use of the `find` results for image display.

#### SOLUTION

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#
#@file img_displays_from_path.sh
#

find /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win \
      -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.png" | \
           sort > tmp_imagepaths.txt

while read -r line; do
  img_fname=$(cygpath -w "${line}")
  "/cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/"\
"python" -u show_img_and_wait.py "${img_fname}"
done < tmp_imagepaths.txt

rm tmp_imagepaths.txt
```

Back on Cygwin's terminal,

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ chmod +x img_displays_from_path.sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ ./img_displays_from_path.sh
Let us show C:\Users\13852\Desktop\testing_cv2_python_win\image_1.png
[Trust me that C:\Users\13852\Desktop\testing_cv2_python_win\image_1.png showed
up fine.]
Now, we are done showing it.
Let us show C:\Users\13852\Desktop\testing_cv2_python_win\image_2.png
[Trust me that C:\Users\13852\Desktop\testing_cv2_python_win\image_2.png showed
up fine.]
Now, we are done showing it.
Let us show C:\Users\13852\Desktop\testing_cv2_python_win\image_3.png
[Trust me that C:\Users\13852\Desktop\testing_cv2_python_win\image_3.png showed
up fine.]
Now, we are done showing it.
Let us show C:\Users\13852\Desktop\testing_cv2_python_win\image_4.png
[Trust me that C:\Users\13852\Desktop\testing_cv2_python_win\image_4.png showed
up fine.]
Now, we are done showing it.
Let us show C:\Users\13852\Desktop\testing_cv2_python_win\image_5.png
[Trust me that C:\Users\13852\Desktop\testing_cv2_python_win\image_5.png showed
up fine.]
Now, we are done showing it.
```

Success! In case it helps you to follow along, here are the five images to use (    ).

---

*Other path stuff*

Here's another small taste of what issues might come getting Windows paths with Cygwin. A lot more of them (from my own curiosity tests) can be seen in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbcWf.png)

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE ~
$ cd 'c:'
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c
$ ls 'c:'
ls: cannot access 'c:': No such file or directory
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE ~
$ cd c:
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c
$ ls 'c:\'
'$Recycle.Bin'            'Program Files'        'System Volume Information'
 cygwin64                 'Program Files (x86)'   Users 
'Documents and Settings'   ProgramData            Windows
 nothing_important
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE ~
$ cd c:\
> # Problem; line-continuation char; I have to [Ctrl]+[C]^C
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE ~
$ cd C:\nothing_important # another one to watch out for is this one
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/nothing_important
$ ls C:\nothing_important
ls: cannot access 'C:nothing_important': No such file or directory
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/nothing_important
$ ls "C:\nothing_important"
nothing_at_all
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/nothing_important
$ cd C:/
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c
$ cd nothing_important\nothing_at_all
-bash: cd: nothing_importantnothing_at_all: No such file or directory
```

I'm using and expanding on the examples given by @mccoolive in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23850515/6505499) (about FFMPEG, but it shows the possible issues).

Though we can actually say that the fault in handling the path comes from Windows `python`, I'm including this to see that even Cygwin's `bash` (`cd` and `ls`) has issues with Windows vs. Cygwin paths.

For even more details, check out [this documentation](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20200501203251/https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html)) from Cygwin.

---

**Footnotes**

**1.** There are two ways that I've used to allow an easier access to Windows `python` through the Cygwin terminal.

The ***first one***, and the one I recommend  using, is to modify your `~/.bashrc` file. I do this as follows. Note that I back up my previous `~/.bashrc` before changing anything.

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ date && date +'%s'
Fri, May  1, 2020  2:01:46 PM
1588363306

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.$(date +'%s').bak

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ find ~ -type f -name "*.bashrc.*.bak" | tail -1
/home/bballdave025/.bashrc.1588363346.bak

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ echo -e "\n\n# Allow access to Windows' version of python, e.g. for cv2\n"\
"alias pythonwin=/cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python\n" >> \
  ~/.bashrc
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Let's see if it worked.

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ pythonwin --version
Python 3.8.2
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ # That as compared to
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ # and as compared to
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ python --version
Python 2.7.16
```

To show a disadvantage of this first approach to the second one, I'll try finding out where this `pythonwin` functionality comes from. Using my usual `which pythonwin` doesn't work, neither does `whereis pythonwin`, nor `locate -b pythonwin`, nor `apropos pythonwin`. I didn't run it, but `find / -name "*pythonwin*"` wouldn't get it either. I actually had to search before I could find a way to get the information (my findings [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28560/291375), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28689/291375), [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10529/291375), [4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28555/how-to-find-applications-path-from-command-line#comment38398_28560), [5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10525/291375), [6](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146699/291375), [7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193424/291375)). The info can be found with either `command -v pythonwin` or `type pythonwin`.

But ...

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE ~
$ which pythonwin
which: no pythonwin in ( #the whole output of my `PATH`# )
```

Note that [aliases take precedence over the `PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17185/291375).

The ***second one*** is to use a symlink. If you want to do this, and you already ran the commands for the `alias`, you can either

a. revert back to your backup. In my case, this would be

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ cp ~/.bashrc.1588363346.bak .bashrc
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ unalias pythonwin
```

b. open your `~/.bashrc` however you want, and manually delete the lines we added.

Now, for the symlink. I put it in the folder where [user-installed programs are supposed to go](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY) ([archived, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> for "/usr/local : Local hierarchy"](https://web.archive.org/web/20200501222134/https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html)), i.e. `/usr/local/bin/`. I'll set things up and check them below.

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ ln -s /cygdrive/c/Users/13852/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe /usr/local/bin/pythonwin
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ pythonwin --version
Python 3.8.2
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ which pythonwin
/usr/local/bin/pythonwin
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ command -v pythonwin
/usr/local/bin/pythonwin

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ type pythonwin
pythonwin is hashed (/usr/local/bin/pythonwin)

bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ readlink /usr/local/bin/pythonwin
/cygdrive/c/Users/13852/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe
```

If you decide that you want to remove this symlink, use

```sh
bballdave025@MY-MACHINE /cygdrive/c/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win
$ unlink /usr/local/bin/pythonwin
```

**2.** It's true that, if I had searched with `'.'` as the base directory of my search, the scripts would have run perfectly. However, other than the situation I've given, with the canonical path, I don't know during which other crazy edge cases the different paths might fail. I think the situation of having a canonical path is sufficient to make it very advisable to use the `cygpath -w` solution.

**3.** As many of you will know, both Cygwin and Python consider the two following filename strings the same.

```
C:\Users\bballdave025\Desktop\testing_cv2_python_win\image_1.png
C:/Users/bballdave025/Desktop/testing_cv2_python_win/image_1.png
```

I actually try to use the forward slash ('/') whenever I'm not finding paths programatically.